# How do I add titles from a database table connecting to other tables and a total

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my current code:

```
Select
  InventoryTransactionDocuments.Name as 'GRV Name',
  InventoryTransactionDocuments.Date,
  InventoryItems.Name as 'Items',
  convert(decimal(16,0),InventoryTransactions.Quantity) as 'Units',
  convert(decimal(16,2),InventoryTransactions.Price) as 'Cost',
  convert(decimal(16,2),InventoryTransactions.Quantity*InventoryTransactions.Price) AS 'Total Cost'
From
  InventoryItems,
  InventoryTransactionDocuments,
  InventoryTransactions
Where
  InventoryTransactionDocuments.Id=InventoryTransactions.InventoryTransactionDocumentId
  And InventoryTransactions.InventoryItem_Id=InventoryItems.Id
```

This returns:

```
GRV Name|Date                     |Items         |Units |Cost  |Total Cost

INV001  |2017-01-10 12:48:14.027  | Coke         | 10   | 9,00 | 90,00
INV001  | 2017-01-10 12:48:14.027 | Sprite       | 10   | 7,50 | 75,00
INV002  | 2017-01-11 14:36:12.036 | Fanta        | 5    | 8,50 | 42,50
INV002  | 2017-01-11 14:36:12.036 | Mountain Dew | 8    | 6,33 | 50,64
```

But what I want is:

```
GRV: INV001
Date:2017-01-10 12:48:14.027
Items  | Units | Cost | Total Cost
Coke   | 10    | 9,00 | 90,00
Sprite | 10    | 7,50 | 75,00
Total: |              |165,00 

GRV: INV002
Date:2017-01-11 14:36:12.036 
Items        | Units | Cost | Total Cost
Fanta        | 5     | 8,50 | 42,50
Mountain Dew | 8     | 6,33 | 50,64
Total:       |              |93,14
```

I have tried adding the total with a UNION All and sum function, but I get a varchar to decimal error.

```
Union All

Select
'Total For GRV','','','','',Sum([Total Cost])
FROM Temp
```

Where temp is set as the top select statement.
The apostrophes have also been changed to is null per column, with no difference.

I would appreciate any help that you can give me to achieve the desired results.

Comment: You're using the old fashioned form of JOINs (`FROM table a, table b WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id`). Please consider using proper joins (`FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b on a.id = b.id`) instead. It's ANSI compliant, and will work even when you port your solution to a different RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, however I am still recieving the error when using Union All and the sum function.

Comment: It's not a good idea to try and format reports in SQL. SQL does a fixed number of columns and a variable number of rows. To get what you want you'd need to use string functions to stick all the data together in _one_ single column. Why do you need to do this? for a report? Who views the report and in what tool?

Comment: A POS system  displays this report. However I don't have access to the source code of the program, so I can't use string functions or other ways to display the report, only the SQL query.